# link_to root_url - doesn't load objects on redirect - I have to then refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, link-to

I'm using `<%= link_to image_tag("logoi.png"), root_path %>` as my main logo and it should reload (if already on homepage) or carry back users to the homepage.

It's currently redirecting to the homepage, however nothing on the homepage loads. I have to then reload the browser for my node objects to display.

routes.rb

```
authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'dashboard#index', as: :authenticated_root
end
```

dashboard_controller.rb

```
def index
    @family_tree = current_user.family_tree
    @nodes = @family_tree.nodes.where(:is_comment => nil)
    @video = Video.new
    @videos = Video.all.where(:is_complete => true)
    @node = Node.new
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possibly that turbolinks isnt working properly with any jquery being used. Try adding

> gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

and requiring it with

> //= require jquery.turbolinks

Not sure if this could be causing issues with node but it was the first thing I thought of after reading the question and the symptoms